# Fine tuning resnet18 for cifar10

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I just want fine tuning ResNet18 on cifar10 datasets. so I just want to change the last linear layer from 1000 to 10.
I tried use `children` function to get the previous layers

```py
ResModel = resnet18(weights=ResNet18_Weights)
model = nn.Sequential(
    *list(ResModel.children())[:-1],
    nn.Linear(512,10)
)
```

so it raised error
`RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32768x1 and 512x10)`
and then I tried this way `ResModel.fc=nn.Linear(512,10)` it works fine.
so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between stacking all layers into a single `nn.Sequential` and overriding only the last layer is the `forward` function:
Your `ResModel` is of type `torchvision.models.ResNet`, while your `model` is a simple `nn.Sequential`. The `forward` pass of `ResNet` has an additional `flatten` operation before the last linear layer -- you do not have this operation in your `nn.Sequential` `model`.

Comment: thanks for saving my days!